# How to handle A4 PDFs which have unrealistic size metadata

Tags: pdf

I work on a software that deals with PDFs a lot. This software requires using Tools [pdf2img](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2img/) and [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) to render the PDFs as image and for further (image based) processing. These PDFs are almost always scanned paper documents of size A4. PDFs exported from programs such as Word or other word processors are also a concern.

In any case, sometimes the PDFs to be processed seem to be created with incorrect metadata regarding the size of the contained document. A concrete example: The following screenshot shows the metadata of a PDF containing a single page with an image of a photographed document (I can't show the actual PDF due to it being a customer document). The Ubuntu file system explorer and common CLI tools will show similar results:

- The file seems to be created by an iOS app
- The page should be ~ 1000 x 1500 mm (30 x 59 inch) in size

[image]

This may or may not be a too generic question: It seems that the assumed size of the page is wrong (the PDF shows a standard A4 document which should have 210 × 297 mm). Probably, the iOS app that created this PDF did not assume the picture taken is an A4 document. I don't expect PDF creators to always correctly do this. This now leaves the task of handling this "error" to me. Are there any typical approaches I can apply to 1) detect and 2) fix these kind of errors?

I currently plan to check this metadata before actually converting the PDF to images which could allow me to set additional parameters when rending the PDF as image. But maybe I am wrong and there could be additional metadata inside the PDFs which would allow me to more correctly handle PDFs such as these.

Comment: There's more than one 'size' in a PDF file. There's the MediaBox, which may be what your dialog there is displaying, and then there's the TrimBox, CropBox, ArtBox, BleedBox. Any of which might be smaller than the MediaBox and may be what your PDF viewer chooses to display. Without seeing the PDF file (or an example you are able to share) I cannot comment further.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your hints. I see that I must investigate a bit more into the details of the mentioned attributes. Maybe using PDFBox a bit might help

Comment: Try `cpdf -page-info in.pdf` to show the absence or presence of the various boxes and, if present, their size in points. I'm afraid you'll have to covert to mm yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot is from Acrobat, the displayed page size is the CropBox (if available). 
There is no technical error with your PDF file. The application took a picture of an A4 document and created a PDF file with a page size in points that matches the image size in pixels. 1043.2 * 1537.8 mm = 2957 * 4349 points so the image in your PDF file should be around this size.
If, from the point of view of your application, this is an error than that's another problem.

The A4 aspect ratio is 210/297 = 0.70707
Your document aspect ratio is 1043.2/1537.8 = 0.67837
The Letter aspect ratio is 612/792 = 0.77272

Assuming you deal only with A4 documents, you could check the aspect ratio of your document and if it sits between, let's say, 0.65 and 0.71 then you can consider the document to be an A4 and if its page size is larger than A4 than scale it down to A4.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Your answer nudged me towards a solution in which I must 1) get the page sizes of all document pages and then handle them differently depending on their size. For that I will try to use PDFtk as it seems to be a mature CLI that could do this for.